# How to allow orders for out-of-stock products?

Tags: magento-1.7, stock

We want to be able to take orders for products that are "out of stock" in Magento. I have enabled backorders in `System > Config > Inventory`, but the "Add to basket" button is still hidden for any products marked as "out of stock" (thus the backorder can't be taken).

For backorders to work properly, do products with stock quantity of 0 need to be marked as "in stock"?  I don't want to have to remove the `if($_product->isSaleable()):` from `catalog/product/view/addtocart.phtml` because that would be hardcoding something that should be configurable from the admin panel.

Have tested this on Magento 1.7 and 1.9, both with the same results.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By changing the settings in `System > Config > Inventory` will only affect the defaults when you create new products, you still need to enable each product to allow backorders.

[image]

Easiest way to do this is select all products you want to allow to be backordered, then select Update attributes from the actions drop down and click submit.

Once the screen has loaded select the Inventory tab from the top left. Then select the change box for 'Backorders' and then click save.

Answer (score 3):

You shoud set the "Stock Availability" to "In Stock"
If that doesn't work either, reindex the stock status