# Out of Stock & Backorder Status: Does default magento behaviour require "In Stock" status to purchase a backorder item

Tags: magento-1.9, inventory, out-of-stock, stock-status, backorder

When a product has: 
qty <1, and
is set to "Backorders: Allow Qty Below 0..."

Is it also required that **Stock Availability** be set to **In Stock** before a customer can purchase this item?

For example:

```
Qty: 1,
Backorders: Allow Qty Below 0,
Stock Availability: Out of Stock
```

Can this product be purchased under default Magento behaviour? Or does it require stock availability to be set to "**In Stock**"?

Magento documentation is silent on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it does.

Check [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/22400/how-to-allow-orders-for-out-of-stock-products) out.

Magento has in-built setting for turning on "Backordering". It is located at 
`System >> Configuration >> Catalog >> Inventory` but this will work only on new products.

For all existing products you still have to turn it on in admin products grid(`Catalog >> Manage Products`) by selecting products and then choosing "Update Attributes" from the "Action" dropdown menu and then submitting it.
In the next screen choose "Allow Backorders..." checkbox and also keep the "Stock Availability" to "In Stock" and click on "Update"/"Save" button.

Hope this clarifies it.